# Find m "smallest" elements from m by n np.array

Tags: python, arrays, element, multidimensional-array

I have a two-dimention ndarray of size `m` by `n` (`m<=n`) like the following:

```
a = [ [1, 2, 3], 
      [4, 5, 6] ]
```

Now I want to greedily find `m` "smallest" elements from the array with a restriction that each row and column can only choose one element, everytime choose the global minimum. My code is as follows:

```
for k in xrange(m):
    index = np.argmin(a)
    i, j = divmod(index, n-k)
    result.append(a[i][j])
    a = np.delete(np.delete(a, i, 0), j, 1)
```

So I would get `result = [1, 5]`, is there any better way to represent the input array `a`, and better algorithm to find these elements wrt speed?

Comment: Is 1, 5 in some regard "better" than 2, 4? Just asking to understand what exactly you're looking for in a "smallest". Always greedily looking for the lowest possible element to remove?

Comment: I agree with @JoachimIsaksson, the problem as posted is not well-defined.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, good observation. But it would be too expensive to find m global smallest elements with the specified restriction, which needs to firstly find all the possible m-elements combination, n*(n-1)*...*(n-m+1)=n!/m!, then calculate the corresponding average value of each case and finally choose the best one that give me the smallest average. Here I am doing large scale processing and I just want to use this greedy algorithm to give me one decent result quickly, which may not be the best. But It would be appreciated if there is an efficient algorithm to find the global minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried an alternative approach:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

nmin = 2000 # number of the smallest values to find in a matrix with unique row and column indexes
nrows = 2000 # number of rows
ncols = 2000 # number of columns
print "Select {} smallest values from {} x {} matrix".format(nmin, nrows, ncols)

matrix = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size = nrows * ncols).reshape(nrows, ncols) # sample 2D array
#print matrix

# ALTERNATIVE: sort once and track-and-skip visited rows and columns
startedat = timeit.default_timer()
seenrows = set()
seencols = set()
order = (divmod(index, ncols) for index in np.argsort(matrix, None))
for iter in xrange(nmin):
    while True:
        try:
            current = order.next()
        except:
            break
        if current[0] not in seenrows and current[1] not in seencols:
            #print iter, current, matrix[current[0]][current[1]]
            seenrows.add(current[0])
            seencols.add(current[1])
            break
alternative = timeit.default_timer() - startedat
print "Alternative approach took: ", alternative

# ORIGINAL: repeatedly find minimum and update matrix
startedat = timeit.default_timer()
for k in xrange(nmin):
    index = np.argmin(matrix)
    i, j = divmod(index, np.shape(matrix)[1])
    #print k, (i, j), matrix[i][j]
    matrix = np.delete(np.delete(matrix, i, 0), j, 1)
    if matrix.size == 0: break
original = timeit.default_timer() - startedat
print "   Original approach took: ", original, "WINNER" if original < alternative else "TIE" if original == alternative else "LOOSER"
```

With the following result:

```
Select 2 smallest values from 2000 x 2000 matrix
Alternative approach took:  0.737312265981
   Original approach took:  0.0572765855289 WINNER

Select 20 smallest values from 2000 x 2000 matrix
Alternative approach took:  0.732718787079
   Original approach took:  0.564769882057 WINNER

Select 200 smallest values from 2000 x 2000 matrix
Alternative approach took:  0.736015078962
   Original approach took:  5.14679721535 LOOSER

Select 2000 smallest values from 2000 x 2000 matrix
Alternative approach took:  6.46196502191
   Original approach took:  19.2116744154 LOOSER

Select 20000 smallest values from 2000 x 2000 matrix
Alternative approach took:  7.90157398272
   Original approach took:  19.189003763 LOOSE
```

Comment: Nice idea to sort only once, my matrix is usually small, within 250*250, and usually m<n. Your approach is faster in a lot of cases during my test. However, I found another more efficient approach, instead of deleting the corresponding rows and cols through "np.delete", just set the corresponding rows and cols to the maximum value, such as matrix[i,:]=1, matrix[:,j] = 1

Comment: Instead of setting invalid cells to max possible value, you could also try using a mask ([link](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html)).

I wanted to avoid doing N^2 operation (the min search) for each iteration.  So basically I traded the N^2-order op for two (2) N-order ops (the set membership lookup).